# Best practices for shipping NuGet packages with global usings inside package-specific MSBuild file?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

Some context: working on distributing a new version of our core NuGet packages that has some breaking changes which can be resolved by just referencing a namespace that has been available for years.

I'm interested in shipping a `{package-name}.props` file inside our NuGet package which will automatically apply the following:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(ImplicitUsings)' == 'true'">
        <PackageReference Include="MyProject" Version="6.1.0" />
        <Using Include="MyProject.NonDefaultNamespace" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is what I don't know how to do:

1. What's the right condition to apply here if I want to apply this `global using` statement to the largest possible number of legacy users? Check if `ImplicitUsings` is enabled? A .NET version? A C# language version?
2. Do I need to include a `PackageReference` to the package inside the `ItemGroup` or is that already done via the package being referenced inside the `.csproj` / `.fsproj`
3. Is this going to be a footgun in other ways I don't know about?

Thanks!

Comment: For additional context, here's the NuGet documentation on shipping `.targets` and `.props` files as part of a NuGet package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/msbuild-props-and-targets

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid adding a `global using` in a nuget package. The problem is that it will add that namespace to *every* file in the consuming project without the consumer explicitly opting in. This could presumably cause type name collisions that could be confusing and difficult to resolve.

I think it would be better to document adding the `<Using>` element to their .csproj, as a way for them to explicitly opt-in to the global behavior.

Comment: The whole point of ImplicitUsings is that they are implicit, and users did implicitly opt into this behavior. This risk is essentially by design. What makes it different when a package is using it?

Comment: No. The user "explicitly" opts to use implicit usings, either by explicitly adding the `ImplicitUsings` to their project to enable the defaults, or by explicitly adding a `<Using Include` to add a non-default. The "implicit" part is that they are "implied" to be added in every single source file. Useful for something like "System", but maybe not so much for a library that is only used in a couple files.

Comment: I fail to understand, Microsoft's SDKs are importing a bunch of namespaces, that may not be used at all, like JSON extensions or platform specific things like CoreGraphics and Maui Xaml. How do you decide this isn't useful? It may be very reasonable for OP's library.

Comment: A library/nuget package is different than an SDK. I don't want Newtonsoft JSON to add any implicit usings to my project. I think an SDK should be very conservative in what they add too.